# The estimateFaces method always returns an empty array for predictions

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow.js

I would like to ask about the reason why the estimateFaces method always returns an empty array for predictions (there is no error either on the console or on the terminal).  I would also like to know about the selection of the TensorFlow.js backend (setBackend('webgl')). What is the differences between WebGL and CPU backends and how to choose the appropriate one?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import axios from "axios";
import { setBackend } from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import * as faceLandmarksDetection from "@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection";
// import myVideo from '../test-video.mp4'; 


function RegisterPage() {
  // const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(true);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [group, setGroup] = useState("");
  // const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null); 
  const [model, setModel] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const runFaceMesh = async () => {
      await setBackend('cpu'); 
  
      const faceMeshModel = faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedModels.MediaPipeFaceMesh;
      const detectorConfig = {
        runtime: "tfjs",
        solutionPath: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh",
      };
      const modelInstance = await faceLandmarksDetection.createDetector(faceMeshModel, detectorConfig);
      setModel(modelInstance);
    };
  
    runFaceMesh().then(() => {
      console.log('Model has been loaded');
    });
  }, []);
  

  const handleCapture = useCallback(async () => {
    const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    console.log('Screenshot has been taken:', imageSrc);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/register", {
        name,
        group,
        image_data: imageSrc,
      });
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }, [name, group, webcamRef]); 

  const detectFace = useCallback(async () => {
    if (
      model &&
      typeof webcamRef.current !== "undefined" &&
      webcamRef.current !== null &&
      webcamRef.current.readyState === 4
    ) {
      const predictions = await model.estimateFaces(webcamRef.current);
      console.log('Predictions:', predictions);
  
      if (predictions.length > 0) {
        console.log('Face Detected');
      } else {
        console.log('No Face Detected');
      }
    // Draw bounding boxes on the canvas, only if canvasRef.current is not null
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
        if (prediction.boundingBox && prediction.boundingBox.topLeft && prediction.boundingBox.bottomRight) {
          const start = prediction.boundingBox.topLeft;
          const end = prediction.boundingBox.bottomRight;
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.rect(start[0], start[1], end[0] - start[0], end[1] - start[1]);
          ctx.lineWidth = 2;
          ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      });
    }
      if (predictions.length > 0) {
        handleCapture();
      }
    }
  }, [model, handleCapture]);   

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('Interval is working');
      if (model) {  
        detectFace();
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [model, detectFace]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Registration Page</h1>
      {/* <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay loop muted playsInline>
        <source src={myVideo} type="video/mp4" />
      </video> */}
        {/* <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowCamera(!showCamera)}>
          Capture Photo
        </button> */}
        {
          <div>
            <Webcam
              ref={webcamRef}
              screenshotFormat="image/png"
            />
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
          </div>
        }
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Group:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={group}
            onChange={(e) => setGroup(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>


        <button type="button" onClick={handleCapture}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );

}

export default RegisterPage;
```

This is my library version:

```
    "@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection": "^1.0.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.4.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^4.4.0",
```

What exactly caused this problem? Please tell me if I'm missing something. Thank you in advance!